# Use another apps search index with Laravel Scout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-scout

I have two different apps with two separate Laravel installs. The 1st one has some models, and its data is indexed with Scout (using the TNT search driver, which created index files on disk, if it's relevant).

Now I would like to use the 1st's models and data (that part is done, I use the same model with a different connexion to the 1st app's database), but I would also like to use the 1st's *index* when using the `search()` method.

Is it at all possible? If so, what would be the required configuration to do?

At the moment, I need to re-index all of my data in the 2nd app, and it's a bit of a waste because if I make any change in App nb. 1, the index won't update on app nb. 2.

The only idea I had at the moment (and I don't like it at all) would be to `rsync` the index files between the two apps, but there has to be some better way!

tl;dr: I have two apps, and I want to use the model/data/search index of one from the other app. Is it at all possible?

Comment: you can send API requests to fetch data.  check for REST Api

Comment: @rodrane while it's true I could make an API to get what I want, I'd still prefer to be able to use the models if I could.